# Angular 8: filter results from an RxJS observable (from Angular.io tutorial)

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

In the Angular.io tutorial ("Tour of Heroes app"), they use this code to return an array of objects from a service:

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#tap-into-the-observable

```
/** GET heroes from the server */
getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log('fetched heroes')),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
    );
}
```

However, if you need to return an *observable with **single result***, they assume that the API provides that service (i.e., the API takes an `id` parameter).

However, what if, instead, you want your **service** to take an `id` parameter, and then ***filter*** the results from the above function:

E.g., in pseudo-code:

```
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  // call getHeroes (as above)
  // filter the results to return only the here who's id property matches the id parameter;
  this.getHeroes().[filter this somehow, and return an observable with just the match]
}
```

How do you accomplish this?

Sorry in advance - I've found similar questions here, but either they rely on an older version of Angular/RxJS or they aren't quite true to the tutorial (e.g., the function returns an array instead of an observable...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a mapping function - you are taking an object of a certain shape (an array of n results), and want to map it to an object of another shape (a single object).

For this you can use the `map` operator in a pipe.

```js
getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.getHeroes().pipe(
    map(heroes => heroes.find(x => x.id === id))
  );
}
```